# Powershell $using variable not working with Invoke-Command in scriptblock

Tags: powershell, using, invoke-command, start-job

I'm trying to use `$using:x` inside an `Invoke-Command` itself called by `Start-Job`, but I can't figure it out:

```
$x = "yeah"

$sb = {
  param($n)
  '{0}: {1}' -f $n, $using:x

  # Does not work
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName PC -ScriptBlock { 'invoke: {0}' -f $using:x }

  # Does not work either
  # $y = 'foo'
  # Invoke-Command -ComputerName PC  -ScriptBlock { 'invoke2: {0}' -f $using:y }

  # WORKAROUND 
  # Invoke-Command -ComputerName PC -ScriptBlock { param($y) 'invoke3: {0}' -f $y } -ArgumentList $using:x
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList 'job' | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

This outputs:

```
Start-Job : The value of the using variable '$using:x' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set in the local session.
```

I know I can simply pass the value with `-ArgumentList` as in my workaround, but I'm curious what would be needed for the `$using:x` to work. Maybe retrieve the current session and pass it to `Invoke-Command` ?

Comment: Do `$x = $using:x` before calling `Invoke-Command` inside the block

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that works! can you explain why? also can you explain why the `$y` route does not?

Comment: Is it because the "using" scope always refers to the global scope, where the scriptblock is defined?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your `$using:y` issue - assigning a literal value to a local variable `$y` and then referencing it in the remote block with `$using:y` works fine

Comment: With powershell `5.1.19041.1682` this https://pastebin.com/5e04iS4R gives me an error about `$using:y` not set in the current session.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the below example syntax to achieve your goal. Because, from your code, I see Variable X is not declared

```
$Log = "PowerShellCore/Operational"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -ScriptBlock {Get-WinEvent -LogName $Using:Log -MaxEvents 10}
```